# A short question about an e identity

Tags: calculus, limits

Why is this $\{(1+\frac1{a_n})^{a_n}=e\}$ true when: $a_n \to -\infty$

$a_n$ is a sequence.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know that it holds if $a_n\longrightarrow +\infty$?

Comment: You mean $+ \infty$?

Comment: Yes I know about plus infinity, I ask about minus infinity, this is not a typo. It just doesn't make any sense...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Put $b_n=-a_n,$ and note then that $$\left(1+\frac1{a_n}\right)^{a_n}=\left(1+\frac{-1}{b_n}\right)^{-b_n}=\left(\left(1+\frac{-1}{b_n}\right)^{b_n}\right)^{-1}.$$ What is the limit of the expression inside the outermost parentheses as $n\to\infty$ (so that $b_n\to\infty$)?

Comment: Nice work! I'll upvote at night. :)

Comment: I guess the minus 1 in the numerator doesn't interrupt the inside expression from going to e. But then it'll become $\frac1e$. I'm probably wrong.

Comment: Actually, for any real $x,$ we have $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{t}\right)^t=e^x,$$ as is discussed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568268/is-it-trivial-to-say-mathop-lim-limits-n-to-infty-1-k-over-n/568291#568291), so in particular, when $x=-1,$ we see that...what?

Comment: Woah! Thanks!!!

Comment: Thank you, @Ahaan! Glad you liked it.