# The limit of $(\frac{x-1}{x})^x$ as $x\to\infty$ is the reciprocal of $e$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \bigg(\frac{x-1}{x}\bigg)^x = \frac{1}{e} $$

Is there any comfortable way to see that this is true?

The following thing occured to me: take log and use taylor series for $\log(1+x)$: $$\log(1-1/x)^x = x\log(1-1/x) = -1-\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{1}{3x^2}-...  $$

If we take the $\lim_{ x\to\infty}$ it is pretty clear all the terms go to zero except the first one. This if log(something) is -1 then this something = $e^{-1} = 1/e$

Seems to work but doesn't help me "feel" it.

Appreciate your help/feedback!

Comment: "Feeling" it is pretty vague. What more are you looking for?

Comment: What's your definition of $e$?

Comment: In general, you can show that $\lim_{x\to \infty} \left( \frac{x+k}{x} \right)^{x}=e^{k}$ by taking the $\log$ and then using L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: [*Slightly* Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/596771/85969).

Answer (score 1):

One pretty common definition of $e$ is $$e=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$ Further, if you have a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n \to x \neq 0$ then you also know $$\frac{1}{x_n}\to \frac{1}{x}$$ Now obviously $e \neq 0$ so $$\frac{1}{e} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n} \\ = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n} \\ = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{-n} \\ = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left[\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{-1}\right]^n \\ = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n$$ Your definition of $e$ is slightly different, but you should be able to make a very similar argument to get the same result.