# Proving the limit of $\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)^n$is $e^{-1}$

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

Find the limit of $\lim_{n \to \infty}({n\over n+1})^n$.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}({n\over n+1})^n=\lim_{n \to \infty}({n+1-1\over n+1})^n=\lim_{n \to \infty}(1-{1\over n+1})^n$$

What Should I do next?

Comment: Can you use L'Hospital's Rule?

Comment: What is your definition of $e$ or $e^{-1}$?

Comment: Do you know the definition of $e$ as a limit ?

Comment: This is the definition of $e^{-1}$ you can't "evaluate" any more than that.

Comment: @graydad how can I use L'Hospital here?

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1350338/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-n-to-infty-left-1-frac1n-rightn-fr and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596771/finding-the-limit-of-left-fracnn1-rightn

Answer (score 18, accepted):

$$
({n\over n+1})^n={1 \over ({n+1\over n})^n} = {1 \over (1+{1\over n})^n}  \to {1 \over e}
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}\lim_{n \to \infty}({n\over n+1})^n=\lim_{n \to \infty}({n+1-1\over n+1})^n&=\lim_{n \to \infty}(1-{1\over n+1})^n\\&=\underbrace{\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{-(n+1)}\right]^{-\frac{n}{n+1}}}_{e^{-\frac{n}{n+1}}}\\&=\frac{1}{e}\end{align}$$

Comment: As for $e^{-\frac{n}{n+1}}$
 we say that $lim_{n \to \infty} -{n \over n+1}=n$?

Comment: @gbox $$\lim_{n\to\infty}-\frac{n}{n+1}=-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1-1}{n+1}=-\lim_{n\to\infty} (1-\frac{1}{n+1})=-1$$

Answer (score 1):

Observing that the exponential and logarithm are inverses of each other, you can apply L'Hopital's rule to get:
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{n}{n+1})^n=\exp \lim_{n\to\infty}(n\ln(\frac{n}{n+1})) 
=\exp (\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(\frac{n}{n+1})}{\frac{1}{n}}) \\
= \exp(\lim_{n\to\infty} -\frac{n}{n+1}) 
=\exp(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-1}{1+\frac{1}{n}})=\frac{1}{e}.
\end{equation*}