# Limit $\lim_{x \to \infty}\left (1- \frac1x\right)^x = ?$

Tags: limits, exponential-function

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1+ \frac1x\right)^x = e$$
, then$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1- \frac1x\right)^x =\; ?$$

I tried $\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1- \frac1x\right)^x = \lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)^x$, but this is not helpful.

Comment: Well, $1-\frac1x=1+\frac{(-1)}{x}$. Does this help you?

Comment: Note that from Bernoulli's Inequality we have for $x>0$$$1\ge\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x\left(1-\frac1x\right)^x=\left(1-\frac1{x^2}\right)^x\ge 1-\frac1x$$Now apply the squeeze theorem and conclude.

Comment: You might have a look at: [limit of $\left( 1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1531366) or [Finding the limit of $\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/596771). You can probably find osme other posts about this limit - for example, you can [search in Aproach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D(1-%20%5Cfrac1x)%5Ex%24&p=1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

$$
1-\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{\frac{x}{x-1}}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x-1}}
$$

so

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^x=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x-1}}\right)^x=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{x-1}\right)^{x-1}} \left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x-1}} \right)=\frac{1}{e}\cdot 1=\frac{1}{e}
$$

Comment: That is a lot more work than one needs.  Have a look at the comment I left under the OP.

Comment: @MarkViola That is true, but I was just trying to give a different approach that perhaps used previously established facts.  I understand why your last inequality holds, but perhaps the OP didn't

Answer (score 2):

Let, $$y=(1-\frac{1}{x})^x$$

$$or, \ln y=x\ln(1-\frac{1}{x})$$
$$or,\ln y=\frac{\ln(1-\frac{1}{x})}{x^{-1}}$$

Now,
$$or,\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\ln y=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\ln(1-\frac{1}{x})}{x^{-1}}$$

Using L'Hospital rule,
$$\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\ln y=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}-\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{x}}=-1$$
So, $y=e^{-1}$.

Comment: The use of logarithms is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} (1- \frac1x)^x =e^{-1} $$ is evaluated  by taking logarithm of both sides of $ y=(1- \frac1x)^x $ and applying the L'Hospital Rule.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the common limit:$\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ (1+\frac { k }{ x } )^ x } =e^ k$

In this case we have,$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ (1+(-\frac { 1 }{ x } )^ x )}$$
So we compare it with $\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ (1+\frac { k }{ x } )^ x } =e^ k$ we have, $k=-1$ and $x=x$

So,
$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ (1+(-\frac { 1 }{ x } )^ x )}=e^(-1)$$
$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ (1+(-\frac { 1 }{ x } )^ x )}=\frac1e$$

Answer (score 0):

*Just another way*.

$$y=\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^x\implies \log(y)=x \log\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ Now, using Taylor series,
$$\log\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)=-\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2 x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$ 
$$\log(y)=-1-\frac{1}{2 x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$ Continuing with Taylor series
$$y=e^{\log(y)}=\frac{1}{e}-\frac{1}{2 e x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

Even for "rather small" values of $x$, the approximation is quite good. For example, for $x=10$, the exact value is $3486784401 \times 10^{-10}=0.3486784401$ while the above formula gives $\frac{19}{20 e}\approx 0.349485$.