# What is $\lim\limits_{n\to {\infty}} (\frac{n}{1+n})^n$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, functions, exponential-function

What is $\lim\limits_{n\to {\infty}} (\frac{n}{1+n})^n$.

Is it possible to write the function $f(x)=x^n$ and since we know $\frac{n}{1+n}\to 1$, so $f(\frac{n}{1+n})\to 1^n=1$. So the limit it $1$. Is it correct. If so, is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: If you mean the limit as $n\to ∞$, then the limit is equal to $\frac{1}{e}$

Comment: Flip it over, look at the limit of $(n+1)/n)^n$, that is, $(1+1/n)^n$. Familiar?

Comment: The problem with you logic is that both the base AND the exponent depend on $n$ simultaneously.

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596771/finding-the-limit-of-left-fracnn1-rightn) and also [other posts linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/596771).

Comment: I have changed $\lim\limits_{x\to {\infty}} (\frac{n}{1+n})^n$ in your post to $\lim\limits_{n\to {\infty}} (\frac{n}{1+n})^n$. (I suppose $x$ instead of $n$ was a typo. And also this is what you wrote in the title, so this is probably what you wanted to ask.)

Answer (score 6):

Observe that

$$
\left ( \frac{n}{n+1} \right )^n \;\; =\;\; \left ( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right )^{-n} \;\; =\;\; \frac{1}{\left (1 + \frac{1}{n} \right )^n}.
$$

Since $\lim_{n\to \infty} \left ( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right )^n$ is a well known limit this should be pretty easy at this point.

Comment: Didn't think of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If $f$ is a continuous function, one could say that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} f\left( \frac n {1+n} \right) = f\left( \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac n {1+n} \right)$, **but** that's **not** what we have here: we have a different function $f$ for each value of $n$, so that as $n\to\infty$, the function $f$ keeps changing as $n$ grows.

You may recall that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left( 1 + \dfrac 1 n \right)^n = e$.

That's the same as $ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left( \dfrac{n+1} n \right)^n = e$.

Here you have the limit of the reciprocal of that, and the reciprocal function is continuous, and that function does not keep changing as $n$ grows, so you end up with $1/e$.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not correct: your reasoning replaces a part of the expression with its limit, while letting the rest variable. This way you can prove the limit is any number.

To have the answer, it is enough to compute the limit of the log of the expression. Now
$$\log\Bigl(\frac n{n+1}\Bigr)^n=n\log\Bigl(1-\frac 1{n+1}\Bigr)\sim_\infty n\cdot \frac1{n+1}\sim_\infty-1. $$
So the limit is $\;\dfrac1{\mathrm{e}}$.

Comment: It is not really useful not use notation such as $\sim_\infty$ when the OP is learning how to deal with indeterminate forms.

Comment: @Pedro Tamaroff: This depends on the O.P.'s syllabus. In my country, this is taught to first year students. My opinion is it's never too soon to learn efficient methods in simple cases.

Answer (score 1):

I've always hated the formula $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n = e$, so I would always substitute $h=\frac{1}{n}$, giving me a new limit $\lim_{h\to 0}(1+h)^\frac{1}{h} = e$

In this problem we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{n}{n+1}\bigg)^n = \lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{n+1-1}{n+1}\bigg)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\bigg)^n$$

Making the substitution $h = -\frac{1}{n+1}$ we have
$$h=-\frac{1}{n+1}$$
$$n+1=-\frac{1}{h}$$
$$n=-\frac{1}{h}-1$$
Giving us
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\bigg)^n = \lim_{h\to 0}\bigg(1+h\bigg)^{-\frac{1}{h}-1}=\frac{1}{\lim_{h\to 0}(1+h)^{1/h}}\cdot\frac{1}{\lim_{h\to 0}(1+h)^1}$$
$$=\frac{1}{e}\cdot\frac{1}{1+0}=\frac{1}{e}$$