# Calculating $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\left(\frac{n}{n+3}\right)^\sqrt{n(n+1)}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to calculate $$\lim_{n\to \infty}{\left(\frac{n}{n+3}\right)^\sqrt{n(n+1)}}$$
Tried by using $$\lim_{n\to \infty} {a^b} = \left(\lim_{n\to \infty}a\right) ^{(\lim_{n\to \infty}b)} $$
but got the notorious $$\lim_{n\to \infty}{1^\infty}$$
 Then I tried with the identity $x=e^{\ln{x}}$:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}{\left(\frac{n}{n+3}\right)^\sqrt{n(n+1)}} = \lim_{n\to \infty}{e^{\sqrt{n(n+1)}\cdot\ln\left(\frac{n}{n+3}\right)}}$$
Now what? My guess is to continue with inequality:
$$>\lim_{n\to \infty}{e^{n\cdot\ln\left(\frac{n}{n+3}\right)}} = 
\lim_{n\to \infty}{e^{n\cdot\ln{n}-n\cdot \ln(n+3)}}$$
And now I'm really stuck...

I'm I on the correct direction? Any tip is welcomed...

Comment: Use that $(1+a_n)^{1/a_n}\to e$ if $a_n\to0$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\left(\frac{n}{n+3}\right)^{\sqrt{n(n+1)}} = \left[\left(1+\frac{-3}{n+3} \right)^{\frac{n+3}{-3}}\right]^{\frac{-3\sqrt{n(n+1)}}{n+3}}\to e^{-3}
$$

Comment: I understand why the base is $e$. But why is the exponent $-3$?

Comment: When you will evaluate the limit at $n->\infty$ then the term $\dfrac{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}{n+3}$ will tend to 1.

Answer (score 5):

**HINT:**

Note that we can write

$$\left(\frac{n}{n+3}\right)^{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}=\left(\left(\frac1{1+\frac3n}\right)^n\right)^{\sqrt{1+\frac1n}}$$

Comment: Well, I probably need another hint...

Comment: The inner expression tends to $1/e^3$ while the outer exponent tends to $1$. Does that help?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand why $(1+\frac{3}{n})^n\rightarrow e^3$. How do we get there from $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\rightarrow e$ ?

Comment: Well, found the answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/568277/473433 . Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure

Answer (score 4):

Note that
$$\sqrt{n(n+1)}\cdot\ln\left(\frac{n}{n+3}\right)=-n(1+1/n)^{1/2}\ln(1+3/n)\\=
-n\left(1+o(1)\right)\left(\frac{3}{n}+o(1/n)\right)=-3+o(1).$$
Hence, as $n$ goes to infinity, the exponent tends to $-3$ and the answer is $e^{-3}$.

Comment: I don't understand the $o$ notation in this context. Is it like in Algorithms efficiency notation? But I want to get a concrete number... (like $e^{-3}$ in the other answer)

Comment: This is the "little-o" notation. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation
Note that $o(1)$ means something that goes to zero. So the limit of the exponent is $-3$ and the answer is $e^{-3}$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Use that as $a_n\to \infty$

$$\left(1+c\cdot \frac{1}{a_n}\right)^{a_n}\to e^c$$

then

$$\left(\frac{n}{n+3}\right)^\sqrt{n(n+1)}=\left[\left(1+(-1)\cdot\frac{ 3}{n+3}\right)^{\frac{n+3}3}\right]^{\frac{3\sqrt{n(n+1)}}{n+3}}$$

which is no more an indeterminate form.