# What is the limit of $ \lim ((x-1)/(x+1))^x$ when $x$ approaches infinity (without l'Hôpital's rule)?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, limits-without-lhopital

this is my first post.
I've been struggling whit this limit for too long (without using l'Hôpital's rule):

$$\lim_{x\to {\infty}} \left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^x$$

My answer is $\frac1e$, but the correct answer should be $\frac{1}{e^2}$.
Could anyone help me understand why? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(A(x)/B(x)\right)$ where
$$A(x)=\left(1-\frac1x\right)^x$$
and
$$B(x)=\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x.$$
You have probably seen that $B(x)\to e$ and $A(x)\to e^{-1}$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: If you only see one of these limits note that by  $A(x)B(x)=\left(1-\frac1{x^2}\right)^x\le 1$ for $x>1$ and by Bernozlli's ineqality also $\ge 1-\frac 1x$

Comment: Very nice variant!

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, but isn't $A(x)\to e^{-1}$ only when $x\to -{\infty}$? My mistake, I didn't specify that the limit is approaching only $+{\infty}$

Comment: @bancheta: Note that $\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^x=\left(1+\frac{-1}{x}\right)^x$. This shows that, as $x\to\infty$, we have $A(x)\to e^{-1}$ if you're familiar with the fact that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{y}{x}\right)^x=e^{y}$.

Comment: @Clayton Yeah, sorry, my bad. It's very late in the night for me and I'm very confused. I was wrong.

Comment: @Clayton Thanks a lot! That is very clear and helpful!

Answer (score 7):

**HINT**

Use that

$$\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^x=\left[\left(1+\frac{-2}{x+1}\right)^{x+1}\right]^{\frac{x}{x+1}}$$

Refer also to the earlier related

- [Calculating $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\left(\frac{n}{n+3}\right)^\sqrt{n(n+1)}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2988915/505767)

(and you can find many other similar examples on MSE)

Answer (score 2):

You can go to exponential : 
for all $x\in \mathbb R_+^*$
\begin{eqnarray}
\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^x&=&\exp\left(x \ln\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)\right)\\
&=& \exp \left( x \ln\left(1-\frac{2}{x+1}\right)\right)\\
&=& \exp\left(x\left(-\frac{2}{x+1}+O(1/x^2)\right)\right)\\
&=& \exp(-2+o(1))\\
&=& \frac{1}{e^2}+o(1)
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: I insist that even though the other solutions are correct, the one I present is systematic (It works for a many related problems)

Comment: The intermediat step $$\exp\left(x \ln(1-O(1/x))\right)$$ in not necessary. And also, why change from big-O to little-o, it is not wrong but it seems also not necessary.

Comment: Sorry you're right, I started doing a first order dvp and realized I needed a second order I edit it. thx It was also confusing since there were no way to go on from this faulty line.

Comment: Only a minor issue of course! That's a nice way to solve these kind of limits! (+1) already given indeed.